# How to setup a virtual server?

Tags: php

I want to create a website on my PC but the PHP wont work.

Is there any software that will allow me to simulate a server on my PC in order to get this (the website) done?

Comment: Download and install Apache?

Comment: [PHP - Installation and Configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could look into using [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) server if you're using windows (XAMPP on [Mac](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html) and [Linux](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html) as well), it's very simple to get up and running and you'll be able to test your PHP in no time.